# Get wordpress featured image URL into a footer script

Tags: wordpress, loops, footer

Is there a way to pull an image url from a query, and have that url echoed into a plugin script that's in the footer of the same page? My problem is that I have a layerslider that needs a static background image. The problem is that the query is ran at the top of the page, so I lose access to the loop by the time the javascript is called in the footer.

I have this query, INSIDE of the normal page loop:

```
/*Normal Page Loop Here*/ 
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

/*Begin Secondary Query to be Inserted into this page*/
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'projects',
'orderby' => 'rand',
'posts_per_page' => 1,
'meta_query' => array(
           array(
            'key' => 'custom_featured',
            'value' => 'on',
            )
        )
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);


    /*Output Results of Internal Page Query*/
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
       the_title();
       the_post_thumbnail('i-need-this-url-in-the-footer-script');        

    endwhile;/*End the secondary query loop*/
    wp_reset_query();


endwhile; endif;/*End the page loop*/
```

I essentially need the URL of the featured image of this new WP_Query inserted into the script that's in the footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Layer Slider
       $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#layerslider').layerSlider({
       globalBGImage: '<?php echo $imagefromloopurlhere; ?>'
     });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get the URL of the image

```
$image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail_size' );  
if($image_src)
     echo $image_src[0];
```

In order to place the variable into the footer you could do something like this:

```
global $project_featured_url;
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
   the_title();
   $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail_size' );  
   if($image_src)
      $project_featured_url = $image_src[0];
   else
       $project_featured_url = 'some default url to avoid javascript error';
endwhile;/*End the secondary query loop*/
```

Then in your footer

```
<?php global $project_featured_url; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Layer Slider
       $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#layerslider').layerSlider({
       globalBGImage: '<?php echo $project_featured_url; ?>'
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's returning an array

Comment: Updated to echo out the image source url from the array

Comment: I've updated my code. I'm trying to get the image URL of the new WP_Query that is actually inside of the normal page loop inserted into the script in my footer. The code that you posted is getting the featured image url of the actual page itself

Comment: I updated my answer to help fix the problem with displaying the variable in the footer, Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This should work....

```
<?php get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
```

just change thumbnail to the image size you need.